# Bash: Zipping/grouping files by common substring

Tags: shell-script, files, zip

I have about 100 files.

They are named like this.

```
3000_ABCD_XXXXXXX.csv
3000_ABCD_YYYYYYY.csv
3000_ABCD_XYXYZYZ.csv

3000_EFGH_XXXXXXX.csv
3000_EFGH_YYYYYYY.csv
3000_EFGH_XYXYZYZ.csv

3000_IJKL_XXXXXXX.csv
3000_IJKL_YYYYYYY.csv
3000_IJKL_XYXYZYZ.csv
```

Currently I'm zipping each file individually but I want to group them based on their common substring like for example `ABCD.zip` will store

```
3000_ABCD_XXXXXXX.csv
3000_ABCD_YYYYYYY.csv
3000_ABCD_XYXYZYZ.csv
```

`EFGH.zip` will store

```
3000_EFGH_XXXXXXX.csv
3000_EFGH_YYYYYYY.csv
3000_EFGH_XYXYZYZ.csv
```

etc.

I'm very new to Unix/Bash scripting. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: `ABCD`,`EFGH`,`IJKL` are not known in advance. Their position and width within the file name is guaranteed, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "pick them up using indexes"?

Comment: Like I know where the 'ABCD' will  be in the file name i.e it will be from index 7 to 11 for eg... but i dont knw that it is called 'ABCD'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob
typeset -A a
for f (./*) {
  [[ $f = (#b)*_(*)_* ]] &&
    a[$match]+=$f$'\0'
}
for z (${(k)a}) {
  echo zip ./$z.zip ${(ps:\0:)a[$z]}
}
```

(remove the `echo` to actually do it when satisfied).

Using `perl` (from `zsh`/`bash` or any other non-csh-like shell):

```
perl -e 'for (@ARGV) {push @{$a{$1}}, $_ if (/_(.*)_/s)}
  system "echo", "zip", "./$_.zip", @{$a{$_}} for (keys %a)' ./*_*_*
```

(again, remove the `"echo",` to actually do it).

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
IFS='
'
set -f
for group in $(set +f; printf '%s\n' 3000_*.csv | sed 's/3000_\([^_]*\).*/\1/' | LC_ALL=C uniq)
do
  set +f
  zip "$group.zip" "3000_$group"*.csv
done
```

Should work in `bash` or a POSIX shell, provided the filenames don't contain newlines.

Comment: That assumes filenames don't contain space, tab newline, globbing (`*`, `?`, `[`) characters. That will run the same zip commands several times.

Comment: @Stéphane, fixed. Forgot the `uniq` at first.

Comment: You also need to fix the locale to C (`LC_ALL=C`). Try for instance with a list of files like `3000_a_a.csv`,  `3000_a@b_a.csv`, and `3000_a_c.csv` in a typical `en_US.UTF-8` locale. That's because in most non-C locales, `_` is ignored (at first) for sorting.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below script.

```
##The find command below finds all the csv files in the current directory. 

find ~/home/file-directory-location/*.csv -type f > filenames.txt

##We know the second substring after _ will contain the index. 
##I am sorting the file based on that second substring and getting the 
##indices into a new file for zipping.
##The uniq will specify how many zip files we are creating.  

LC_ALL=C sort -t_ -k2,2 filenames.txt | cut -d '_' -f 2 | LC_ALL=C uniq > indexes

##Now, for the created indices just zip the CSV files based on the index name. 
while read index; 
do
        tar cvzf "$index".tgz /home/file-directory-location/3000_"$index"*
done <indexes
```

Comment: If any of the `cvs` files in `~/home/file-directory-location` are of type _directory_, then you will include all the regular files in there. I'm not sure what's the point of your `find` command there. You've got some missing quotes in there. You need LC_ALL=C for sort and uniq.

Comment: I just want to get the list of files that need to be zipped before I find out the indices. So, I use the above find command to get the list of `csv` files.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I added the quotes for the variable. Please let me know if this is fine.